# How to assign Hash ID ref id for dynamic element in angular 4, 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am sorry if my question was silly, i am having 30+ static ng-container with some unique static #hashtagID but i want to create them dynamically with help of ngFor

```
public lists = ['food', 'book', ........, 'cook']
```

expecting output :

```
<ng-container #food></ng-container>
<ng-container #book></ng-container>
..
..
<ng-container #cook></ng-container>
```

So i tried almost all ways but no luck,

```
1: <ng-container *ngFor="#id of lists"><ng-container>
2: <ng-container *ngFor="let id of lists" #{{id}}><ng-container>
3: <ng-container *ngFor="let id of lists" #+"id"><ng-container>
4: <ng-container *ngFor="let id of lists" #{id}><ng-container>
5. <div *ngFor="let id of lists" #id></div>
6: <div *ngFor="let id of lists" [id]="id">
```

i am using this #hashTagID as viewContainerRef in .ts file.

**@ViewChild('food', {read: ViewContainerRef }) private  food: ViewContainerRef;**

Please someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you add an example of using ViewContainerRef?

Comment: @yurzui added example

Comment: So you're going to have 30+ such lines as `@ViewChild('food', {read: ViewContainerRef }) private food: ViewContainerRef;`?

Comment: no not yet,so far i have only done for 5 but still 25+ are there so i was trying to do with some iterate or some loops. And first trying to accomplish this above thing :/

Comment: Awesome !  could you please paste your answer below :D so that i can accept as answer :) @yurzui you almost covered 80% logic for my code on this link :D  thank you thank you so muchhhh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solution could be creating a directive that will take hash as input and also have reference to `ViewContainerRef`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[hash]',
})
export class HashDirective  {
  @Input() hash: string;

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

Now you can write template as:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of lists" [hash]="item"></ng-container>
```

And finally you will be able to get reference to desired `ViewContainerRef` through `ViewChildren`:

```
@ViewChildren(HashDirective) private hashes: QueryList<HashDirective>;

lists = ['food', 'book', 'cook'];

getContainerFor(name: string) {
  return this.hashes.find(x => x.hash === name).vcRef;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.getContainerFor('food'));
}
```

**[Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/pMtH8xeUo5pUUGWzDy1S)**