# Anchor scrolling only works on second click in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a very basic setup on a very long page:

```
<a href="/technicalmanagerreport/4e8485d9-5751-4684-9d24-0af2934dd390#h2">test</a>
<h2 id="h2">LOL</h2>
```

First time I click the link, it jumps down very fast and then back to top. Second time it works. If I click the link, and then another link and then the link again same behavior. So it needs to be two clicks in a row. Any ideas or maybe work arounds??

After some more digging:

```
<a href="technicalmanagerreport/4e8485d9-5751-4684-9d24-0af2934dd390#lol">test</a>

 <div *ngFor="let group of report?.assetGroups">

    <div><a href="technicalmanagerreport/4e8485d9-5751-4684-9d24-0af2934dd390#{{group?.code}}">{{group.name}}</a></div>
 </div>


<div *ngFor="let group of report?.assetGroups">
    <div id="{{group?.code}}">{{group?.name}}</div>
    <div *ngFor="let subGroup of group?.assetSubGroupList">
        <h4>{{subGroup.name}}</h4>
      </div>
</div>

<div id="lol">lol</div>
```

The test link works as expected. Can it be something with the other values coming from a call to a REST service, that is an async call?

Comment: Strange.  Do you have any other libraries you're using that may conflict?

Comment: I am using coreui, but I could try to test it in an new empty angular project.

Comment: If you look in my initial post its only for dynamically calculated links. I also notice when I hover over the link its first technicalmanagerreport/4e8485d9-5751-4684-9d24-0af2934dd390#... and then after a second or two the value is calculated. Its like Angular is doing some delayed calculation on the value. Could be same applies when I click on ot first time, value is being calculated. And thats why it works second time?

Comment: Nopes I was wrong, its also with static links. It works on all other pages. The page is huge can it be the amount of elements on the page?

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I have a similar problem... I found out that the page is getting refreshed on the change of URL hence the abnormal behaviour. The answer to this question didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only solution I could find for this issue is wrapping the scroll function with a setTimeOut function. Although its not a best practice, this approach solves it for sure.

```
  scroll(link: string) {
  window.location.href = this.href + '#' + link;
  setTimeout(() => {document.querySelector('#' + link).scrollIntoView()}, 0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I was technically unable to recreate the issue, but the possible reason could be because you haven't implemented the HashLocationStrategy properly or maybe using the PathLocationStrategy as mentioned in this reference: [Angular Routing Navigation](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/navigation/)

A work around for this could be

Option 1: Using fragments

In your HTML file

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']" fragment="h2"></a>
```

In your Typescript file

```
 ngOnInit() {
     this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
      try {
          if(this.fragment) {
              document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
          }
      } catch (e) { }
    }
```

Option 2 : Just create method and scroll

In your HTML file

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

In your .ts file

```
scroll(el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth"});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, highly appreciated. I will try that. However I did some more findings. If you look my initial page, you can see I have a working link on the same page. I am starting to believe its related to links coming from an async source?

Comment: I really like your option 2, then I dont have to generate an url. Do you know how to dynymically do that? I tried. <div (click)="scroll(group.code)">{{group.name}}</div> and <div #{{group.code}} id="{{group?.code}}">{{group?.name}}</div> but with no luck.

Comment: Maybe you can try it with ng-container and ngFor loop as explained here > [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212285/how-to-assign-hash-id-ref-id-for-dynamic-element-in-angular-4-5)

Comment: I think it all related to another problem. I just tried your option one and get following error: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1000' is not a valid selector. I will create another post for it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You were unable to use querySelector since Angular does not directly allow DOM rendering, you need to import `ElementRef` from `@angular/core` and use that and angular's `Render2` . You can refer to [link](https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba)

Answer (score 0):

if your using `scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'` then you should add this below line

```
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled'
```

in app.module.ts script

Example:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled' // ------->   Add this Line
    }), ComponentsModule],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
```